# How to send parameter in session scope through url rewriting?

Tags: java, jsp

How can I assign sessionscope to my parameter role in query string in the function below ?

My jsp function is :

```
function check()
{
    if(localStorage.role === ‘member’)
    {
       window.location=“http://localhost:8084/project/memberPage.jsp?role=“ + 
       local.Storage;
    }
}
```

But my memberPage.jsp only receive parameter role in sessionscope.
How can I assign sessionscope to my parameter role in the link ?
Thank a lot for replying

Comment: Sorry, but the question doesn't make any sense. A URL parameter is sent as part of the URL. It doesn't have any scope. The server will receive it, can read its value using `HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`, and can do whatever it wants to do with this value. Of course, for something to be sent, the **JavaScript** variable `local` must exist, and must be an object with a property named `Storage`. There is no such thing as a "jsp function". This is JavaScript code. It's executed in the browser, not on the server.

Comment: My index.jsp:

<script>
    function check()
    {
        if(localStorage.role === ‘member’)
        {
           window.location=“http://localhost:8084/project/memberPage.jsp?role=“ + localStorage.role;
        }
    }
</script>

My memberPage.jsp:
<body>
Your role: ${sessionScope.role}
</body>

I use JSTL.
How can I assign sessionCcope to my parameter role in the link so that I can print in memberPage.jsp?
Sorry for not making clear question

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a JavaScript string that will contain the value of a session attribute? If that's what you're asking: `... + "${theSessionAttribute}"`. Of course, if the session attribute contains a double quote or a new line, the generated JS code will be invalid.

Comment: So my link will be: http://localhost:8084/project/memberPage.jsp?role=“ + localStorage.role + "${theSessionAttribute}" ? Really thank you a lot